# Does jenkins job dsl plugin support "parameter filter"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is "parameter filter" supported in Job DSL plugin? What I am trying to do is to [copy artifacts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) from another project when the build parameter `task_id` has the same value as the current project, e.g.

- Build step: Copy artifacts from another project
- Project Name : SomeJob
- Which build : Latest successful build
- Parameter filters : `task_id=${task_id}`

In Job DSL documentation, the following contexts are supported but I don't find "parameter filter":

- includePatterns
- excludePatterns
- targetDirectory
- flatten
- optional
- buildSelector

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not yet supported by Job DSL, but a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/825) changing this has been submitted 2 hours ago.